# How to fill out the bounding boxes with a gaussian blur while streaming yolov4?

Tags: detection, blur, yolo, darknet, yolov4

i am new to yolov4 and I have the following problem. I trained my yolov4 tiny network to detect faces and it runs on a jetson nano. I am using the following code to run the detection over my zed camera:

./darknet detector demo data/obj.data cfg/custom-yolov4-tiny-detector.cfg custom-yolov4-tiny-detector_best.weights -c 0

I would like to fill out the bounding boxes with a gaussian blur in some kinda way to blur my detected face. I looked in the /src/detector.c file and found some functions where drawing takes place in some way but couldnt figure out where i need to change the functions. I would really appreciate your help!

Thank you in advance.